# fuelphp htaccess for multiple app directory not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fuelphp

I have a directory structure like below.

```
public_html/
       /abc/
       /xyz/
       /pqr/
```

there is a index.php in each these directories, abc,xyz,pqr.

now whenever is there any request like `domain.com/abc/def/ghi` should be rewritten to `domain.com/abc/index.php/def/ghi`

```
domain.com/xyz/def/ghi => domain.com/xyz/index.php/def/ghi
domain.com/pqr/def/ghi => domain.com/pqr/index.php/def/ghi
```

What should be the .htaccess file and where it should be placed?

I have .htaccess file in each directory(abc,xyz,pqr) like below, but it is not working. it is showing 404 page not found. Please guide me to handle all these rewrite conditions.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But this is not working... If this is right .htaccess then please tell me if there is any other server side problem. I am setting up this on CentOs server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problem with my directory access, I was needed to update the access for content directory(domain.com) in apache config file(httpd.conf)

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a `RewriteBase /abc` to deal with the subfolders.